# Django migration error . TypeError: expected string or buffer

Tags: django

here is the models.py

```
class Order(models.Model):
    ORDER_STATUS = (
        ('created' , 'Created') , 
        ('paid','Paid'),
        ('shipped','Shipped'),
        ('refunded','Refunded'),
        )

    status = models.CharField(max_length=120 , choices=ORDER_STATUS , default='created')
    cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart)
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserCheckout , null=True)
    address = models.ForeignKey(UserAddress , related_name='useraddress' , null=True)
    Order_total_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10 , decimal_places=2)
    order_id = models.CharField(max_length=20 , null=True , blank=True )
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True , auto_now=False)
    delivered_by = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True , auto_now=False)
```

here is the error i am getting

```
match = datetime_re.match(value)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

I am getting this error when adding the field delivered_by to the model.How can i resolve this error.Thank  you

Comment: Please post the full stack trace for the error.

Answer (score 0):

You must define the **str** or **unicode** method in your model, str in python 3 or Unicode in python 2. I solve this using unicode(myfield) in the method I told you before.